# How did Arab media report the events of the Hamas attack on Israel?

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, media, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza

The Wiki article in Arabic about [October 7th](https://ar-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%B7%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D8%B5%D9%89?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) (linked is a Google translation) is notable for portraying the attack as a purely military operation and avoids any discussions of the crimes against Israeli civilians. This makes me wonder - is this also how Arab media reported the events of October 7th? I can obviously go lookup Al Jazeera's reporting in English quite easily but its much harder to figure out what Arab media reported locally in the Arab language.

Comment: +1 What do you expect us to explain in response to this question?

Comment: @C.F.G I'd like to see links to articles by major Arab newspapers writing in Arabic for a local audience about the events of Oct 7th. Could also be links to TV broadcasts or high quality English language summaries of Arab media.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/64096/how-do-palestinian-schools-teach-about-the-holocaust and https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40702/how-does-israel-teach-the-displacement-of-the-arab-population-in-1948-nakba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Arabic media, the 7th Oct Hamas attack on Israel is referred to as "Operation Al-Aqsa Flood", already giving it a military operation sense.

The Arabic version of AlJazeera reported the attack as a military operation in few of its articles in Arabic, some examples here:

[1 - Watch...the resistance storms Kafr Azza and captures some occupation soldiers](https://www.aljazeera.net/news/2023/10/8/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%85-%D9%83%D9%81%D8%B1-%D8%B9%D8%B2%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B6)

[2 - Al-Aqsa flood.. Learn about the main points of clash between the resistance and Israel](https://www.aljazeera.net/news/2023/10/7/%D8%B7%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D8%B5%D9%89-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%86%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%83)

[3 - How did the “Al-Aqsa Flood” dispel the myth of Israel’s invincibility?](https://www.aljazeera.net/programs/2023/10/7/%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D8%AF-%D8%B7%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D8%B5%D9%89-%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D9%84)

One fron Alarabiya.net

[4 - Watch.. Palestinian armed men infiltrate the settlements and confrontations with Israeli forces](https://www.alarabiya.net/arab-and-world/2023/10/07/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B7%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%BA%D8%B2%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9)

An example from almasryalyoum.com (Egypt today)

[5 - What is the secret of the success of Operation Al-Aqsa Flood? Strategic expert Samir Faraj answers](https://www.almasryalyoum.com/news/details/3000123)

An example from SANA (The Syrian Arab News Agency)

[6 - Al-Aqsa flood... The resistance is invincible and the occupation is reeling](https://sana.sy/?p=1976913)

Comment: I think this could be a great answer if it also included a few other media outlets in Arabic.

Comment: @JonathanReez added three more examples from three other sources

Answer (score 10):

Al-Jazeera in English seems to have adopted the line largely overlooking the atrocities of October 7, and focusing on the Israeli retaliation:
[*On October 7, Gaza broke out of prison*](https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2023/10/14/on-october-7-gaza-broke-out-of-prison)
[*Israel revises down toll from October 7 attack to ‘around 1,200’*](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/10/israel-revises-death-toll-from-october-7-hamas-attack-to-1200-people)
[*Why the Palestinian group Hamas launched an attack on Israel? All to know*](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/10/7/palestinian-group-hamas-launches-surprise-attack-on-israel-what-to-know)
[*Western coverage of Israel’s war on Gaza – bias or unprofessionalism?*](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/10/29/western-coverage-of-israels-war-on-gaza-bias-or-unprofessionalism)

> On October 7, Hamas launched an unprecedented attack on military outposts and communities in southern Israel, killing more than 1,400 Israelis and taking more than 200 hostages back to Gaza, according to Israeli officials.
>
> The same day, Israel launched a relentless bombardment of Gaza that has killed more than 8,000 people, about 40 percent of whom are children.

This is in line with the general opinion among the Palestinians, as can be see from [a widely circulating poll](https://www.pcpsr.org/), who refuse to believe that Hamas and other groups committed atrocities on October 7. Hezbollah leader Hassan Nasrallah even claimed that most civilian casualties resulted from people caught in cross-fire between the IDF and the attackers.

The Saudi Arabia press was apparently given, for political reasons, some leverage in criticizing Hamas, which resulted in what is probably [the harshest criticism of the Hamas atrocities in the Arab media](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/sknkh94dp):

> Journalist Haitham Hasnin noted that Saudi coverage differed from that of Qatari media. When former Hamas leader Khaled Mashal was interviewed on Al-Arabiya, he faced a relatively belligerent line of questioning.
>
> Mashal was asked, **"Do you apologize for what happened to Israeli civilians on October 7?"** When the former head of Hamas's political bureau hesitated to respond, the host interjected, **"You say this is legitimate resistance in your eyes, but what people in the West saw on their TV screens were Hamas' violations against civilians."**

[This exchange with English subtitles can be watched at the Middle East Media Research Institute (MEMRI) web page.](https://www.memri.org/tv/hamas-leader-abroad-khaled-mashal-october-seven-israeli-civlians-no-apologies-hizbullah-arab-countries-do-more)

Saudi media apparently also took Hamas to task for the consequences of the Hamas attack for the Palestinians:

> Veteran journalist Abdulrahman al-Rashed warned Palestinians, "They (the armed groups) are stealing your children for the tenth time." He expressed concern that "many Arab youths are filled with blind admiration, which could replicate what happened in Afghanistan, Syria and Iraq, where many jihadists emerged due to media-fueled recruitment."

A selection of reports from MEMRI, about the coverage in the Middle Eastern media in the days immediately following October 7:

*October 8:*
[Al-Jazeera Airs Exclusive Footage Obtained From Bodycams Worn By Hamas's Al-Qassam Brigade During Invasion Of Erez Military Post In Southern Israel](https://www.memri.org/tv/jazeera-airs-exclusive-footage-obtained-bodycams-hamas-al-qassam-brigade-invasion-erez-israel-military-post)
[Saudi Journalist: The Hamas Attack Will Have Devastating Results; It Harms The Palestinians And Serves Only Iran](https://www.memri.org/reports/saudi-journalist-hamas-attack-will-have-devastating-results-it-harms-palestinians-and-serves)
[Pakistani Dailies Express Support For Hamas Attack In Israel, Predict Halt In Saudi-Israel Normalization Process](https://www.memri.org/reports/pakistani-dailies-express-support-hamas-attack-israel-predict-halt-saudi-israel)

*October 9:*
[Column In Qatari Al-Watan Daily: Hamas Attack On Israel – Like Prophet Muhammad's Attack On Jews Of Khaybar In 628](https://www.memri.org/reports/column-qatari-al-watan-daily-hamas-attack-israel-%E2%80%93-prophet-muhammads-attack-jews-khaybar-628)
[Qatar And Qatari Press Express Unreserved Support For Massive Hamas Terror Attack On Israel, Hold Israel Solely Responsible For It](https://www.memri.org/reports/qatar-and-qatari-press-express-unreserved-support-massive-hamas-terror-attack-israel-hold)

*October 10:*
[Iranian TV Host Mohammad Reza Bagheri: 'There Should Be No Mercy For Israeli Women Or Old Ladies Wounded Or Killed In The Hamas Invasion Of Israel – To Hell With Them!'](https://www.memri.org/reports/iranian-tv-host-mohammad-reza-bagheri-there-should-be-no-mercy-israeli-women-or-old-ladies)
[Arab Social Media Users Criticize Hamas Large-Scale Attack: Defacing Corpses, Raping Girls, Abducting Elderly Women Are All Against Islam](https://www.memri.org/reports/arab-social-media-users-criticize-hamas-large-scale-attack-defacing-corpses-raping-girls)

*October 11:*
[Lebanese Politicians To Hizbullah: Don't Involve Lebanon In A War Against Israel](https://www.memri.org/reports/lebanese-politicians-hizbullah-dont-involve-lebanon-war-against-israel)

*October 12:*
[Pro-Iran Lebanese TV Channel Posts Hebrew-Language Video Addressing "The Occupation Settlers": The Solution For Rocket Attacks Is For You To Leave Palestine, As Fast As A Rocket](https://www.memri.org/tv/pro-iran-lebanon-tv-airs-video-calling-settlers-leave-palestine-rocket)

*October 13:*
[Egyptian Media Blame Israel For Escalation, Express Support For Hamas Attack: 'This Is The Second October Victory'](https://www.memri.org/reports/egyptian-media-blame-israel-escalation-express-support-hamas-attack-second-october-victory)
[On Social Media, Arab Intellectuals Condemn Hamas' Widescale Attack On Israel, Saying It Serves Iran's Agendas, Hinders Peace Efforts, And Brings More Pain And Suffering To Palestinians](https://www.memri.org/reports/social-media-arab-intellectuals-condemn-hamas-widescale-attack-israel-saying-it-serves-irans)

Comment: The OP says they're ideally looking for news targeted to Arabs (and thus in Arabic), but it's a solid assumption to make that Al-Jazeera won't be **more** critical in Arabic than they are in English, so this sets a good ceiling on what they'll report in Arabic.  _(Comment reposted to fix directionality)_